# WordPress - AutoPlay iFrame video off required

Tags: wordpress, iframe, embed

So I've embedded a video into my WordPress website using the following code

```
<div class="videoWrapper"><iframe src="http://www.genericwebsitename.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/generic-website-name-goes-in-here...mp4" width="300" height="300"></iframe></div>
```

I have attempted to add autoplay=0, autoplay=false but nothing seems to be working. It always auto plays.

As you can see, this is not a youtube link, the video file is uploaded to the WordPress site itself and linked via a iFrame tag.

Looking through the forums I cannot seem to find an answer that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of iframe use bellow format

**You can use video tag source, like this:**

```
  <video width="640" height="480" controls="controls" type="video/mp4" preload="none">
    <source src="http://example.com/mytestfile.mp4" autostart="false">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
```

Comment: @WillWebb If the answer helpful try to give a up-vote thanks! :)